# Convert C# Entity Framework linq query to SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am converting the C# linq query to SQL, LINQ never return the values.

But the same query I wrote in SQL returns some values. Can anyone help me find out what the issue is for my SQL query?

LINQ query:

```
var query = from l in _DbContext.Licenses
            join lp in _DbContext.LicenseParts on l.PartNumber equals lp.PartNumber
            join lpc in _DbContext.LicensePartConfigurations on lp.Id equals lpc.LicensePartId
            join p in _DbContext.Products on lp.ProductId equals p.Id
            join lsn in _DbContext.LicenseSerialNumbers on l.Id equals lsn.LicenseId
            join lact in _DbContext.LicenseActivations on new { a = lsn.Id, b = lp.ProductId } equals new { a = lact.LicenseSerialNumberId, b = lact.ProductId }
            where lact.AccountId == AccountId && JsonExtensions.JsonValue(lact.ActivationInfoJSON, "$.SubscriptionKey") !=
                    " " && (JsonExtensions.JsonValue(lact.ActivationInfoJSON, "$.IsConverted") == null || JsonExtensions.JsonValue(lact.ActivationInfoJSON, "$.IsConverted") == "0" || JsonExtensions.JsonValue(lact.ActivationInfoJSON, "$.IsConverted") == "false") && p.Name == "ClearPass Legacy"
            select new SubscriptionKeys { SubscriptionKey = JsonExtensions.JsonValue(lact.ActivationInfoJSON, "$.SubscriptionKey"), CustomerMail = JsonExtensions.JsonValue(lact.ActivationInfoJSON, "$.CustomerMail"), CustomerName = JsonExtensions.JsonValue(lact.ActivationInfoJSON, "$.CustomerName") };

        response.PageSize = pageSize;
        response.PageNumber = pageNumber;
        response.Model = await query.Distinct().ToListAsync();
        response.ItemsCount = response.Model.Count();
```

SQL query:

```
SELECT
    l.AccountId,CustomerMail,
    JSON_VALUE(ActivationInfo, '$.SubscriptionKey') 
FROM
    Licenses l
JOIN
    LicenseParts lp ON l.PartNumber = lp.PartNumber
JOIN
    LicensePartConfigurations lpc ON lp.Id = lpc.LicensePartId
JOIN
    Products p ON lp.ProductId = p.Id
JOIN
    LicenseSerialNumbers lsn ON l.Id = lsn.LicenseId
JOIN
    LicenseActivations lact ON lsn.Id = lact.LicenseSerialNumberId 
                            AND lp.ProductId = lact.ProductId
WHERE
    lact.AccountId = 'QWNjb3VudDoxNTMwNDAzMi00MWM2LTExZTktOWYzMy1kMzQxZjE5OWZlYjM='
    AND JSON_VALUE(lact.ActivationInfo, '$.SubscriptionKey') != ' '
    AND (JSON_VALUE(lact.ActivationInfo, '$.IsConverted') = NULL OR
         JSON_VALUE(lact.ActivationInfo, '$.IsConverted') = 0 OR
         JSON_VALUE(lact.ActivationInfo, '$.IsConverted') = 'false')
    AND p.Name = 'ClearPass Legacy'
```

Comment: EF Core is an ORM, not a replacement for SQL. It uses entities and classes, not objects. You shouldn't have to use JOINs at all, the ORM will generate the JOINs as needed based on the relations between entities. You *can't* use anything in LINQ-to-Entities that doesn't map directly to SQL. That means you can't use any functions unless there's a direct mapping to SQL. Whatever `JsonExtensions` is, it's not one of them.

Comment: Only a few very common methods like `string.Contains` or `String.StartsWith` are mapped directly. For the rest, you need to use methods in [DbFunctions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbfunctions?view=efcore-5.0). There are no Json-related functions

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Most RDBMS today support JSON-in-SQL - so those `JsonExtensions` _could_ very-well be valid `[DbFunction]` methods. Just sayin'...

Comment: You could enable logging and sensitive data logging then you can compare the generated SQL output and the desired.

Comment: @Dai were talking about an ORM, not a database. Besides, all databases handle JSON differently so there's no single way of handling this. In fact, one could make a *very* strong argument that what's needed is mapping those JSON strings to objects, not hand-coding the mapping.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, EF is an ORM, and EF _can_ support using JSON functions in Linq expressions which are rendered into the actual SQL, and _yes_ those JSON functions would be RDBMS-specific and non-portable between (say) Postgres and MSSQL.

Comment: @Dai and M means Mapping, which means the ORM should be able to map those JSON strings to objects instead of leaking the database's implementation into code and forcing developers to hand-code that mapping. `JSON_VALUE(lact.ActivationInfo, '$.IsConverted')` is mapping code

Comment: `JSON_VALUE` is a function in SQL Server, I don't know why you're calling it "mapping code". https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: **Don't do this!** `JSON_VALUE(lact.ActivationInfo, '$.IsConverted') = NULL` - comparing to `NULL` in SQL **must only** be done using `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` - comparing with the equal operator will **not work** !

Comment: @user8837476 you could use [computed columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations#computed-columns) to map the `SubscriptionKey` and `IsConverted` attributes to entity properties so you can use them in queries. If you use proper relations as well, you could reduce the query to `_dbContext.LicenseActivations.Where(lact=>!lact.IsConverted }} lact.IsConverted==null).Select(lact=>new {lact.AccountId,SubscriptionKey});` or `Select(lact=>new {AccountId=lact.LicensePart.License.AccountId...`

Answer (score -1):

To start from a valid point, execute the code where it fires this linq query and use sql profiler to catch it up. That is a good way to find the exact equivalent sql statement it finally produces and executes. You need to set up a trace to sql profiler prior to execute the linq. Get the statement and then you can compare with the sql you already have.

this sql:

```
(JSON_VALUE(lact.ActivationInfo, '$.IsConverted') = NULL
```

is not equal to:

```
(JsonExtensions.JsonValue(lact.ActivationInfoJSON, "$.IsConverted") == null
```

as in first case you compare to database NULL value using '=' and this requires ansi_nulls off to work properly and it is not a good practice.

Comment: That's incorrect. `NULL` isn't equal to anything so the SQL condition will never match any `NULL`s. The LINQ-to-Entities condition `x.Prop == null` will be converted to `Prop IS NULL` by EF itself. There's no reason to use DBNull.Value. That was used in ADO.NET before nullable types were introduced

Comment: Panagiotis Kanavos depends on ansi_nulls setting. It matches pretty fine. Check it yourself:
create table #test_null(id int)
insert into #test_null values(1)
insert into #test_null values(null)
set ansi_nulls off
select * from #test_null where id = null
set ansi_nulls on
select * from #test_null where id = null
drop table #test_null

Comment: Yes, if you misuse the database you can do a lot of things. That's rather career limiting though. And a reason for termination. And a great way to fail *every* SQL interview question. Just because some systems misused NULL settings 30 years ago doesn't mean there's any reason to keep doing it. I can't stress enough just how *bad* this idea is. That's `wrapping-a-fuse-in-aluminum-foil` kind of bad

Comment: Sure but its not a matter your - or mine - preference or industry standards or whatever... since the SQL posted was ' = NULL' indicates that settings are probably not ansi.

Comment: Actually, it *is* a standard. `= NULL` is a bug, plain and simple. Such code is typically found in questions asking `Why can't I find nulls`? Let's say that saying `it's a preference` to a SQL Saturday, SQL meetup or .NET meetup wouldn't go very well.

Comment: No its not a bug its a bad practice in most cases and that is different. And it can be a standard for you and me and lots of others but there it is not, it exists and probably this is what causes different data responses - it is a good candidate.

Answer (score -1):

ORMs like EF Core are meant to Map Objects to Relational constructs. Instead of trying to write SQL in C# through LINQ, you should try to Map the attributes you need to entity properties.

In this case the `SubscriptionKey` and `IsConverted` fields should appear in the table itself, either as proper fields or computed columns. If that's not possible, you could use [computed columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations#computed-columns) to map the `SubscriptionKey` and `IsConverted` attributes to entity properties so you can use them in queries.

In your `LicenseActivation` class add these properties:

```
    public bool? IsConverted {get;set;}

    public string? SubscriptionKey {get;set;}

    public string? CustomerEmail {get;set;}
```

In your DbContext, you can specify computed columns with `HasComputedColumnSql`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<LicenseActivation>()
        .Property(b => b.SubscriptionKey)
        .HasComputedColumnSql("JSON_VALUE(ActivationInfo, '$.SubscriptionKey')");

    modelBuilder.Entity< LicenseActivations >()
        .Property(b => b.IsConverted)
        .HasComputedColumnSql("JSON_VALUE(ActivationInfo, '$.IsConverted')");

    modelBuilder.Entity< LicenseActivations >()
        .Property(b => b.CustomerEmail)
        .HasComputedColumnSql("JSON_VALUE(ActivationInfo, '$.CustomerEmail')");

}
```

This will allow you to use the properties in LINQ queries.

You shouldn't have to use all those JOINs either. It's the ORM's job to generate JOINs from the relations between objects. If you add proper relations between the entities the query could be simplified to :

```
var binValue='QWNjb3VudDoxNTMwNDAzMi00MWM2LTExZTktOWYzMy1kMzQxZjE5OWZlYjM=';
var query=_dbContext.LicenseActivations
                .Where(lact=>
                    lact.AccountId == binValue 
                    && (lact.IsConverted==null || !lact.IsConverted))
                .Select(lact=>new { 
                            lact.AccountId, 
                            lact.SubscriptionKey, 
                            lact.CustomerEmail});
```

or, if the `AccountId` fields don't hold the same data :

```
.Select(lact=>new { 
    AccountId =lact.LicensePart.License.AccountId, 
    lact.SubscriptionKey, 
    lact.CustomerEmail
});
```

EF Core will generate the appropriate SQL and JOIN clauses to get from `LicenseActivation` to `License` based on the relations between the entities

Comment: the user ask to convert to SQL, not improve the c# linkq code

Comment: And that's what I answered. The fields can be mapped. After that it's up to the OP to write the query any way they want, although the actual conversion doesn't even need any joins.

Comment: He better pick up the produced sql query from the sql profiler and start from there. If he alters the code he may alters the existing logic. It is pointless to change anything to the c# linq as his objective is to create an sql equivalent statement.